# Converting nested optional list to optional list in Java?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming

I have an `optionalIdList` ( `Optional<Set<String>> optionalIdList`) that I want to iterate over, and then convert back to `Optional<Set<String>>`.  My code thus far is like this:

```
optionalIdList
              .map(
                  idList ->
                      idList.stream()
                          .map(
                              id ->
                                  filterIds(
                                      partnerIds
                                  )))
              .flatMap(streamOfLists -> streamOfLists.map(item -> item.orElseGet(ImmutableSet::of)));
```

The `filterIds` list returns `Optional<Set<String>>`

However with my current solution I get the following error:

> Required type: `Optional<Set<String>>`
>
> Provided: `Optional<Object>`

Is there a nice way to do what I want to do?

Comment: Can you add code that populates your `optionalIdList` with sample data? It's hard to debug if we don't know which data is in there. Also include your imports please needed to run.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Can you show some expected inputs and outputs?

Comment: Is it me or does that code style look ugly?

Comment: rethink your design - what does `Optional<Set<String>>` solve that an empty `Set` doesn't solve for you?

Comment: also, why does the  `.map(id -> filterIds(partnerIds))` ignore the `id`? voting down the question for being unclear..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT: For some reason I assumed `filterIds` returns a single `String`, and not an `Optional<Set<String>>` as you wrote it does.

Here's the updated answer:

```
Optional<Set<String>> output =
    optionalIdList.map(idList -> idList.stream()
                                       .map(id -> filterIds(partnerIds))
                                       .filter (Optional::isPresent)
                                       .map (Optional::get)
                                       .flatMap (Set::stream)
                                       .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```